# Make MySQL's ORDER BY dynamic in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to make the `ORDER BY` dynamic in mysql query in node.js. But it's not working. I `console.log` the multiQuery variable and everything looks perfect but when ran it simply doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
var order,
    multiQuery;
if(req.query.o){
    order = req.query.o;
}else{
    order = "views";
}
multiQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(Category) AS Count FROM posts;';
//PROBLEM LIES HERE IN THE SECOND ONE
multiQuery += 'SELECT ID, Title, Img_path, Category, Views FROM posts WHERE Category = ' + connection.escape(category) + ' ORDER BY' + connection.escape(order) + 'DESC LIMIT ' + start_from + ', 15;';
connection.query(multiQuery, function(err, result){
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not work:

```
SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY 'baz';
```

This does work :

```
SELECT foo FROM bar ORDER BY baz;
```

Did you try removing the quotes that `connection.escape` adds?

Try using this:

```
function escapeSansQuotes(connection, criterion) {
  return connection.escape(criterion).match(/^'(\w+)'$/)[1];
}
```

then use `escapeSansQuotes(connection, order)` instead of `connection.escape(order)`.

Answer (score 0):

try using a proper spacing for each token

```
//PROBLEM LIES HERE IN THE SECOND ONE
multiQuery += 'SELECT ID, Title, Img_path, Category, Views 
           FROM posts WHERE Category = ' + connection.escape(category) + 
           ' ORDER BY ' + connection.escape(order) + 
           ' DESC LIMIT ' + start_from + ', 15;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you did enabled the multi-query into your connection object.

http://nickolayconsulting.com/node-js-and-multiple-sql-calls-in-one-query/

> Support for multiple statements are disabled by default for security
>   reasons (it allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not
>   properly escaped). To use this feature you have to enable it for your
>   connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```