# How to add ASC or DESC to an ORDER BY SQL query

Tags: sql, node.js, express, sql-order-by

This is an example of a query I've tried:

```js
const order = req.params.order
connection.query('select * from students order by first_name key=?', order, (err)=>{
...
});
```

By default without specifying the way, I retrieve the information ordered by first_name asc.

I would like the data ordered by asc or desc according what has been sent through the params.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make MySQL's ORDER BY dynamic in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625688/make-mysqls-order-by-dynamic-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that req.params. order = ASC or DESC.
So try this:

```
connection.query(`select * from students order by fisrt_name ${order}`, order, (err)=>{
...
});
```

or

```
const myQuery = `select * from students order by fisrt_name ${order}`;
connection.query(myQuery, order, (err)=>{
...
});
```

Comment: Yes of course it works, but my aim was to escape these parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Do this. If order is undefined it will order by ASC by default. If it is defined, it will order by the parameter. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
connection.query(
    `select * from students order by first_name ${order ? order : 'ASC'}`
    , order, (err)=>{
...
});
```